# How can I track a PHP script that is being fired by browser in shell?

Tags: php

I'm firing a php script with jQuery from an HTML interface I make to make things easier. I set the script so I can keep running even if the browser session is lost so I can close the browser.

I wish to track which scripts are currently running in shell (using 'ps -aux' or htop..) but do cannot locate these tasks under the name of the script or with PHP in the process name. Any suggestions? also, what would be the best way to push these tasks into some workload/jobs manager ?

Thanks

Comment: it can be in 2 ways, log in a text file or initiate an email :)

Comment: You could also make an API call (from inside shell script) to a known endpoint - whenever endpoint is hit this increments a counter (stored in a DB or a file) by 1

Comment: On the man page for `exec()` a nice example of how to do this has already been explained... http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#88704

Comment: Based on webserver configuration, PHP runs for example inside the apache2 or fpm process.